# Datagridview Cell Value (Get) Returned Nothing. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm trying to make it so that a user can search for whatever they want in a datagridview called `dgvDynamic` using a textbox called `txtSearchDGV` and a button called `btnSearch`. When `btnSearch` is clicked, only cells containing the text inside `txtSearchDGV` should appear in the datagridview however, the program crashes and says "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned Nothing." What does this mean and what do I need to do to fix it? Thank you.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        Dim temp As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvDynamic.RowCount - 1
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgvDynamic.ColumnCount - 1
                If dgvDynamic.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = txtSearchDGV.Text Then
                    MsgBox("Item found")
                    temp = 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
        If temp = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Item not found")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: There's no actual filtering going on there. You say that only matching records should be displayed but you're always displaying everything, based on that code. Where EXACTLY does the data come from in the first place? Especially if it comes from a database, you can populate a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid via a `BindingSource`. You can then set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource` and rows will be shown and hidden as appropriate.

Comment: Your right, it doesn't actually filter the datagridview, I just realised. It just shows a message box when the item is found or wether it is not.

Comment: Would you like me to give you the rest of the code for when it is binded and such? What I actually wanted the code to do was to show all the cells in the datagridview which met the search criteria. How would I do that? Thank you.

Comment: That's really a separate question but, put simply, when you find a matching cell, add it to the `SelectedCells` collection of the grid or else set its `Selected` property to `True`.

Comment: So how would I actually search the grid view and then apply the filter? Thank you.

Comment: That is yet another question. Please keep each post to a single, specific question, and show us what you have tried on that subject.

Answer (score 0):

If the cell has no value here:

```
If dgvDynamic.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString = txtSearchDGV.Text Then
```

then that `Value` property is `Nothing`, i.e. no object, and you can't call a method, e.g. `ToString`, on an object that doesn't exist.  One option would be to use `CStr` instead, which will handle nulls:

```
If CStr(dgvDynamic.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value) = txtSearchDGV.Text Then
```